Googlesheet GETPIVOTDATA Function using Date as reference in another cell
In googlesheet i'm getting a "field combination not found" error when using the function GETPIVOTDATA. I'm getting the error when using another cell as a reference date.
This is the formula I'm using:
=GETPIVOTDATA("Calls",$Q$1,"Date",Q46,"Name",R46)
wherein:
$Q$1 is the cell containing the reference pivot.
Q46 is the cell containing a valid date.
R46 is the cell containing the reference Name.
Please see image below...
here is the scrnshot
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1plMbUhSQkyt7x06VigJadbxd3mLx2gBPyMUS3K7OhjE/edit?usp=sharing
What i'm trying to do is pull the data in the pivot and display it into another table by changing the value in the cell "Q46" (reference date) and "R46" (referance name).


You may try:
=getpivotdata(S$45,$Q$1,"Date",text($Q46,"mmmm d, yyyy"),"Name",$R46)



Oh this works. Thank you so much.
And also I apologize because I also posted this questions on other forums.
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/getpivotdata-function-in-googlesheet-with-date-as-reference.57257/#post-307984
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/getpivotdata-function-error-in-googlesheet-when-making-date-as-reference.1260915/#post-6195548
https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/1dpoegu/getpivotdata_function_in_googlesheet_with_date_as/

Cool. You could always just leave a post note (at the end of description or so) that the question has been #Crossposted from next on...
